# Limit of the supremum

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, continuity

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^n$ be an absolutely continuous function that $|f(t)|$ is nonincreasing, as $t\to\infty$. How can I compute

\begin{equation*}
\lim_{t\to0}\dfrac{1}{t}\sup_{r\in[0,t]}|f(r)|^2
\end{equation*}
?

I cannot solve this because of the following. Since $f$ is non increasing, the maximum of its value is at $t=0$. Thus, 
\begin{equation*}
\lim_{t\to0}\dfrac{1}{t}\sup_{r\in[0,t]}|f(r)|^2\leq \lim_{t\to0}\dfrac{1}{t} |f(0)|^2=\infty.
\end{equation*}
Is this reasoning right?

Comment: By the conditions on $f$, your $\le $ is in fact $=$, but the limit may be $0$ if $f$ is constant $0$

Comment: Your $f$ takes vector values. What do you mean by _nonicreasing_?

Comment: Thank your for your question Julian Aguirre. I meant the norm is non increasing.

Answer (score 0):

The problem looks like it was misunderstood or typed incorrectly. Certainly, $|f|$ being nonincreasing makes the introduction of supremum seem pointless: it's just $|f(0)|$. Then either $|f(0)|=0$ and the limit is $0$, or $|f(0)|> 0$ and the limit is $+\infty$. Either way, the absolute continuity does not come into play, and the point of exercise remains unclear.